# Optimization - Encode a string and get hexadecimal representation of 3 bytes

Tags: c#, optimization, encoding

I am currently working in an environment where performance is critical and this is what I am doing :

```
var iso_8859_5 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-5");

var dataToSend = iso_8859_5.GetBytes(message);
```

The I need to group the bytes by 3 so I have a for loop that does this (i being the iterator of the loop):

```
byte[] dataByteArray = { dataToSend[i], dataToSend[i + 1], dataToSend[i + 2], 0 };
```

I then get an integer out of these 4 bytes

```
BitConverter.ToUInt32(dataByteArray, 0)
```

and finally the integer is converted to a hexadecimal string that I can place in a network packet.

The last two lines repeat about 150 times

I am currently hitting 50 milliseconds of execution times and ideally I would want to reach 0... Is there a faster way to do this that I am not aware of?

**UPDATE**

Just tried

```
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(dataByteArray);
hex.Replace("-", "")
```

to get the hex string directly but it is 3 times slower

**Ricardo Silva's answer adapted**

```
public byte[][] GetArrays(byte[] fullMessage, int size)
        {
            var returnArrays = new byte[(fullMessage.Length / size)+1][];
            int i, j;
            for (i = 0, j = 0; i < (fullMessage.Length - 2); i += size, j++)
            {
                returnArrays[j] = new byte[size + 1];

                Buffer.BlockCopy(
                    src: fullMessage,
                    srcOffset: i,
                    dst: returnArrays[j],
                    dstOffset: 0,
                    count: size);

                returnArrays[j][returnArrays[j].Length - 1] = 0x00;
            }
            switch ((fullMessage.Length % i))
        {
            case 0: {
                returnArrays[j] = new byte[] { 0, 0, EOT, 0 };
            } break;
            case 1: {
                returnArrays[j] = new byte[] { fullMessage[i], 0, EOT, 0 };
            } break;
            case 2: {
                returnArrays[j] = new byte[] { fullMessage[i], fullMessage[i + 1], EOT, 0 };
            } break;
        }    
            return returnArrays;
        }
```

Comment: So the string `"abcd"` would be converted to `0063626100000064`? I don't see why you would want to encode a string in such a way, essentially increasing the space required by a factor of at least 2.66

Comment: Following Iso 8859-5 it would be 636261 000064 since I regroup bytes by 3

Comment: It is then placed as the data part of a network packet

Comment: So your integers are only 24 bits long? I still don't understand why the network packet contains the string doubly-encoded (being very ineffecient with regard to space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line below you will get the total byte array.
    var dataToSend = iso_8859_5.GetBytes(message);

My sugestion is work with Buffer.BlockCopy and test to see if this will be faster than your current method.

Try the code below and tell us if is faster than your current code:

```
    public byte[][] GetArrays(byte[] fullMessage, int size)
    {
        var returnArrays = new byte[fullMessage.Length/size][];

        for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < fullMessage.Length; i += size, j++)
        {
            returnArrays[j] = new byte[size + 1];

            Buffer.BlockCopy(
                src: fullMessage,
                srcOffset: i,
                dst: returnArrays[j],
                dstOffset: 0,
                count: size);

            returnArrays[j][returnArrays[j].Length - 1] = 0x00;
        }

        return returnArrays;
    }
```

EDIT1: I run the test below and the output was 245900ns (or 0,2459ms).

```
[TestClass()]
public class Form1Tests
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetArraysTest()
    {
        var expected = new byte[] { 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x00 };
        var size = 3;

        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        var iso_8859_5 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-5");

        var target = iso_8859_5.GetBytes("012");
        var arrays = Form1.GetArrays(target, size);

        BitConverter.ToUInt32(arrays[0], 0);

        stopWatch.Stop();

        foreach(var array in arrays)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < expected.Count(); i++)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(expected[i], array[i]);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}ns", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000000));
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I looked to your code and I have only one suggestion. I understood that you need to add EOF message and the length of input array will not be Always multiple of size that you want to break.
BUT, now the code below has TWO responsabilities, that break the S of SOLID concept.
The S talk about *Single Responsability* - Each method has ONE, and only ONE responsability.
The code you posted has TWO responsabilities (break input array into N smaller arrays and add EOF). Try think a way to create two totally independente methods (one to break an array into N other arrays, and other to put EOF in any array that you pass). This will allow you to create unit tests for each method (and guarantee that they Works and will never be breaked for any changed), and call the two methods from your class that make the system integration.

Comment: Thx! As you can see in my edit, I needed to adapt your code a bit since the data is not always a multiple of 3 and I need to determine where to put the end of transmission symbol but I did see an improvement

Comment: 0,3 to 0,4 ms for the 150 messages!

Comment: The only thing that I didn't understand, before you've got 50ms for 150 messages and now got you 0,3ms for same 150 messages? Or was 50ms for each of messages and now 0,3ms for each?

Comment: My bad I had 50 ms for 150 messages and now 0,3ms for each group of 50 messages (3 group total)

Comment: Very nice, maybe there's other way to get more performance (like use some method written in C++), but I don't know how. Although, drop from 50ms to range of 0,9 - 1,2ms is very very good. For your high performance system, this time is enough?

Comment: Probably but it would go against the reason why we are using c#. We decided that performance gain was not enough versus development time. About 5% gain since we are using mono so code is compiled to c++